# stylus nodejs css-parse error

Tags: node.js, parsing, stylus

I'm new at Stylus, installed nodejs and stylus and all is ok except when I try to convert a .CSS file to .styl with > "stylus -C filename.css" (also tried with --css) on terminal at file folder, I'm working on kubuntu 14.04 , I'd appreciate any help, oh,  I also installed all the libraries I could find with Synaptic for nodejs css-parse or so, the error I get is this:

> /usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/node_modules/css-parse/index.js:62
>       throw err;
>             ^
>   Error: property missing ':' near line 2:12
>       at error (/usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/node_modules/css-parse/index.js:57:15)
>       at declaration (/usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/node_modules/css-parse/index.js:189:33)
>       at declarations (/usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/node_modules/css-parse/index.js:219:19)
>       at rule (/usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/node_modules/css-parse/index.js:481:21)
>       at rules (/usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/node_modules/css-parse/index.js:103:56)
>       at stylesheet (/usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/node_modules/css-parse/index.js:73:16)
>       at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/node_modules/css-parse/index.js:485:10)
>       at new Converter (/usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/convert/css.js:29:15)
>       at Function.module.exports [as convertCSS] (/usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/convert/css.js:16:10)

THNX

Comment: Can you provide `filename.css`?

Answer (score 0):

Look on line 2 of your `filename.css` file. It's not valid CSS. It's missing a colon. Fix that then retry.